# C# ListView in WPF, Cant see content

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

Shortly, I'm new to grid and WPF and for some reason I cannot see my content within my ListView and I'm pretty much sure that Grid causes it.

```
 <Grid Canvas.Left="223" Canvas.Top="228">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="9*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="28*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="8*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="21*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="29*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="29*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ListView HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="123" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="589" Name="LibraryList" Margin="-188,-76,-141.001,-10" IsEnabled="False" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Grid.RowSpan="2" >
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Item Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ItemName}" Width="70"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Copy Number" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding CopyNumber}" Width="85"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Guid" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Guid}" Width="100"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Print Date" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Date}" Width="90"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Best Seller" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding BestSeller}" Width="90"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Category" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Category}" Width="70"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Sub Category" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding SubCategory}" Width="80"/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
```

The implementation is:

```
ManageCtors.InitJournal(int.Parse(copyNumber.Text), itemName.Text, DateTime.Parse(TimePrinted.Text), int.Parse(Guid.Text), (JournalCategory)Enum.Parse(typeof(JournalCategory), SubCategory.Text));

//Add to ListView
string[] row = { itemName.Text, copyNumber.Text, Guid.Text , TimePrinted .Text, Category.Text , SubCategory.Text = "None" };
ListViewItem _listViewItem = new ListViewItem();
_listViewItem.Content = row;
LibraryList.Items.Add(_listViewItem.Content);
```

Any Idea?
BTW: Sometimes I get a message: input was not in the correct format.

Comment: Check your Debug Output window in Visual Studio for Binding Errors

Comment: Your input string format errors are probably coming from the ManageCtors line for one of the .Parse operations

Answer (score 0):

The data you are binding to is an array of strings, but in each of the GridViewColumn's you are binding by name. This is probably the problem.

You would be best to model the data row out to its own class and set an instance of the class to the ListViewItem.Content property.

```
public class ItemData
{
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
    public int CopyNumber { get; set; }
    public Guid Guid { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string BestSeller { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public string Subcategory { get; set; }
}


ItemData row = new ItemData { 
            // set each property value 
        };
ListViewItem _listViewItem = new ListViewItem();
_listViewItem.Content = row;
LibraryList.Items.Add(_listViewItem.Content); // not sure if you need content here
```

I think you would also be better off binding the ItemsSource on the ListView rather than adding items directly on to the ListView Items collection.

```
ObservableCollection<ItemData> items = new ObservableCollection<ItemData>();
// add your ItemData instances to the items collection
LibraryList.ItemsSource = items;
```

You would also be better off following the MVVM pattern, of which there is a lot of advice on StackOverflow and elsewhere to get you started.